# Error when storing checkpoints to Google Cloud bucket

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator

I run a Tensorflow model with the ML Engine on Google Cloud, and the checkpoint saver fails to save files on the bucket. I am using TensorFlow 1.4, and `tf.Estimator` with the method `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`.

These are the log records, where `gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423` is the argument `model_dir` given for the estimator:

```
E  master-replica-0 Couldn't match files for checkpoint gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
I  master-replica-0 Create CheckpointSaverHook.  
I  master-replica-0 Restoring parameters from gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/. 
W  master-replica-0 Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://e-trial-central1/models/1530351907.8359423/.
```

Things I've already tried, following suggestions from other posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612129/error-couldnt-match-files-for-checkpoint-gs-obj-detection-train-model-ckpt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669695/errortensorflowcouldnt-match-files-for-checkpoint)):

1. Saving to a regional bucket (us-central1) instead of a multi-regional. This results in the same error.
2. Using a simpler path, which doesn't include the '.' in the folder name. This results in the same error.
3. Saving to a local path, rather than the bucket. This works! But I want the files on the bucket eventually.

In contrast to other posts, what's a bit weird here is that the checkpoint path is actually corrupted. There is '.' after the model dir instead of the Tensorflow pattern (`model.ckpt`).
Also, after failing when I look in the model dir in the bucket there are actually files there - the TF events file, and the `.index`, `.meta` and `.data...` files, but the checkpoint files are not there.

Any ideas what would cause this? or what to try next?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by moving to a more recent version of Tensorflow (1.8).